# Access variable outside function in Node

Tags: node.js

I've created a small encryption script. However, I'm having issues accessing a variable from one function in another function

```
    var triplesec = require('triplesec');

var data = 'secretthings'
// Encrypt Function
triplesec.encrypt({
    key: new triplesec.Buffer('secretkey'),
    data: new triplesec.Buffer(data),
}, function (err, buff) {
    if(!err) {
        global.data = buff.toString('hex')
        //console.log(buff.toString('hex'))
    }
});

// Decrypt Function
triplesec.decrypt({
    data: new triplesec.Buffer(global.data, "hex"),
    key: new triplesec.Buffer('secretkey')
}, function (err, buff) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log(buff.toString());
    }
});
```

When I run the above code, I get an error stating:

buffer.js:67
    throw new TypeError('must start with number, buffer, array or string');

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Either make something a global variable and mutate it, or pass it explicitly as arguments to function calls.

Comment: Move the entire `triplesec.decrypt` function call to the end of the `if` statement where `ciphertext` is defined, because it's only available in that block.

Comment: i made it a global and now i get an error that says: 'buffer.js:67
    throw new TypeError('must start with number, buffer, array or string');'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`triplesec.encrypt`and `triplesec.decrypt` seems like a asynchronous function.

So you should `decrypt` after `encrypt` callback.

Maybe you should write like this :

```
var triplesec = require('triplesec');

// Encrypt Function
triplesec.encrypt({
    key: new triplesec.Buffer('secretkey'),
    data: new triplesec.Buffer('secretthings'),
}, function (err, buff) {
    if(!err) {
        var ciphertext = buff.toString('hex')
        console.log(buff.toString('hex'))
    }

    // Decrypt Function
    triplesec.decrypt({
        data: new triplesec.Buffer(ciphertext, "hex"),
        key: new triplesec.Buffer('secretkey')
    }, function (err, buff) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log(buff.toString());
        }
    });

});
```